# How do you add a field to a table (MySQL) in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to create a cold fusion(9) script that adds a field ('pageTitle') to a MySQL table ('pb_page'). Can someone enlighten me and teach me how this is done? Thx!

Comment: Run `ALTER TABLE` in `<cfquery>` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfquery name='alterdb' datasource='mydsn'>
alter table `mydatabase`.`mytable` add column `myfield` varchar(255) NULL after `lastfield`;
</cfquery>
```